# Proof of greatest element of a non-empty set

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers

I am working from Elliott Mendelson's "Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis," which I am thoroughly enjoying thus far.

The proof I am struggling with comes at the end of a section on order relations in the chapter on natural numbers:

By a greatest element of a set $B \subseteq P$ we mean an object $z$ such that $z\in B$ and $(\forall u)(u\in B \implies u \leq z)$.

If $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq P$ and $A$ is bounded above (that is, $(\exists w)(\forall u)(u \in A \implies u \leq w)$), then $A$ has a greatest element. (*Hint:* Let $B = \{w: (\forall u)(u\in A \implies u \leq w)\}$. By hypothesis, $B \neq \emptyset$. Apply the least number principle.)

The hint basically prescribes how to satisfy the requirement of a greatest element possessing the property that there exists some $z$ such that $(\forall u)(u\in A \implies u \leq z)$. In particular, define $B$ as given in the hint; since $A$ is bounded above, $B$ is non-empty. Since $B$ is, in turn, non-empty, it possesses a least element by the least number principle. This least element of $B$ is clearly the "$z$" referred to above, i.e., the greatest element of $A$. I have been struggling for quite a while with demonstrating that this "$z$" is, indeed, contained in $A$. I have attempted the method of proof by contradiction considering the alternative case that $z \notin A$, but can't seem to figure a means to arrive at a contradiction. I've also considered induction proofs as a means of reaching a contradiction, but likewise can't reach any contradictions. Can anyone provide an extra tip or approach to explore, please?

Comment: The most natural and simple way to prove the general claim that "any nonempty finite *totally* ordered set admits a maximum" is by induction on the cardinality of the support set. Reasoning by contradiction is not at all required. There is an alternative method of arguing via *Noetherian* ordered sets - of which finite sets form a particular instance - but the direct induction on the finite cardinality is by far the most straightforward method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a write-up which I think only uses concepts up to that point in the book:

Let $z$ be the smallest element of $B$.
Assume $\forall a \in A \; (a \not = z)$.

This means $a<z$.

Now notice that $z \not = 1$ since $A$ is not empty.

This means $z = S(w)$ for some $w$. (Theorem 1.1 in that chapter of the book).

But this says

$$a < S(w) = z$$

meaning

$$a \leq w < z$$

so $w \in B$ and $z$ is not minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose $z \notin A$. Then, for any $a \in A$, we have $a\leq z$ (because $z \in B$) but $a \neq z$. So $a <z$ or $a \leq z-1$. This proves that $z-1 \in B$ but this contradicts the fact that $z$ is the smallest element of $B$.

Comment: Thank you! Subtraction hasn’t been defined as of yet in the development up to this exercise, but I understand the reasoning of your proof by contradiction. I’ll try to come up with a similar proof using only notions defined so far.